# Partition function of a two level system

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, partition-function, two-level-system

So I have a system made up of $N$ indistinguishable fermions that interact with each other. Also, the system is made up of two energy levels, and their gap is $D$.

Therefore, trying to write down the partition function I used 
$$Z(T,V,1) = \sum g(E)e^{-\beta E}=g(0)+g(D)e^{-\beta D}$$ where the $g$ is the degeneration of the system.

Proceeding, wanting to arrive at the calculation of the heat capacity $C_v(T)$, I am calculating the energy $U$, and from there, well, with another derivation and I have the $C_v(T)$.

Now, my question is the following: to show that $C_v(T)$ goes to zero for $T\to0$ and $T\to\infty$, I can simply calculate the limit of that quantity. But I want to use a more physical approach in the way I could give an explanation in few lines. And I was thinking to use the concept of density of probability.
Is that correct, or is it totally wrong?

Comment: I have heavily edited your question to make it more readable. Please review the edits to make sure I have captured your question correctly. Also, please note that we use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations here. I have done this for you this time, but I suggest your learn more about using MathJax for future posts on this site.

Comment: Alright, I will have a look at the MathJax. Thank you very much!